# get the index of previous occurrence of a value in a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B' ]})
    code
0   A
1   A
2   B
3   B
4   C
5   C
6   C
7   B
8   A
9   C
10  C
11  B
```

I want to create another column which gives the items in code before the next consecutive occurrence of the same value, as well as the target index of the previous occurrence. For example:

```
    code target prev_idx
0   A [] NaN
1   A [] 0
2   B [] NaN
3   B [] 2
4   C [] NaN
5   C [] 4
6   C [] 5
7   B [C, C, C] 3
8   A [B, B, C, C, C, B] 1
9   C [B, A] 6
10  C [] 9
11  B [A, C, C] 7
```

What's the fastest way to go about this?

Comment: How big is this column of data and how many unique values are there? I'm thinking about this from an optimization standpoint, but I feel like the cost would be too high if it's a smaller number of either.

Comment: @irene please accept the answer if this was what you were looking for. Note that changing the first prev_idx to np.nan causes the following indices to be floating point numbers so I removed that section in the modified version of the code.

Comment: @luthervespers The dataframe has a few thousand entries, although for the full version, I want to apply this to a dataframe with another column `id` to which this same function must be applied. That would bring it to a total of a few hundred thousand entries. @tozCSS works though it can be slow even a single dataframe with a few thousand entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another way. It's faster than the answer posted by @tozCSS for my actual application (thousands of rows), probably because we don't search the entire dataframe every time (`target = (df.code[:row.name]==row.code)`). As a bonus, it also works even if the indexing is not from `0` to `len(df)`.

```
def get_target(row, data, col):
    if not row['first_of_seq']:
        return []
    else:
        return data.iloc[data.index.get_loc(row['prev_idx'] + 1): data.index.get_loc(row.name)][col].tolist()

def get_elements_in_between(data, col):
    data = data.copy()

    # get the index of the previous occurrence of the item
    old_idx_name = data.index.name
    data = data.rename_axis('dummy_idx').reset_index()
    data['prev_idx'] = data.groupby(col)['dummy_idx'].shift()

    # check if the item is the first of consecutive occurrences or not
    data['first_of_seq'] = ((data['prev_idx'] - data['dummy_idx']) != -1) & (~data['prev_idx'].isna())

    # convert floats to integers (and NaN to <NA>)
    data['prev_idx'] = data['prev_idx'].astype('Int64')

    # revert to the original indexing
    data = data.set_index('dummy_idx')
    data = data.rename_axis(old_idx_name)

    # get the targets using the target indices
    data['target'] = data.apply(get_target, args=(data, col), axis=1)
    
    data.drop(columns=['first_of_seq'], inplace=True)
    
    return data
```

We get:

```
>> get_elements_in_between(df, 'code')
    code    prev_idx    target
0   A   <NA>    []
1   A   0   []
2   B   <NA>    []
3   B   2   []
4   C   <NA>    []
5   C   4   []
6   C   5   []
7   B   3   [C, C, C]
8   A   1   [B, B, C, C, C, B]
9   C   6   [B, A]
10  C   9   []
11  B   7   [A, C, C]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def get_target(row,df=None):
    """
    this function is applied to all rows in df
    row.name is the index of the current row
    row.code is the value in the code column
    did row.code value appear ever before the current row?
    if so return the segments starting from its last appearance till current row
    """
    target = (df.code[:row.name]==row.code)
    if target.any():
        prev_idx = target[target].index[-1]
        return {'target':df.code[prev_idx:row.name].tolist()[1:],
                'prev_idx':prev_idx}
    elif target.empty:  # if this is the first row
        return {'target':[],'prev_idx':-1}
    # return the index of the previous row
    return {'target':[],'prev_idx':target.shift().index[-1]}

df[['target','prev_idx']] = df.apply(get_target,df=df,axis=1,result_type='expand')
df
```

to get

|  | code | target | prev_idx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | [] | -1 |
| 1 | A | [] | 0 |
| 2 | B | [] | 1 |
| 3 | B | [] | 2 |
| 4 | C | [] | 3 |
| 5 | C | [] | 4 |
| 6 | C | [] | 5 |
| 7 | B | ['C', 'C', 'C'] | 3 |
| 8 | A | ['B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B'] | 1 |
| 9 | C | ['B', 'A'] | 6 |
| 10 | C | [] | 9 |
| 11 | B | ['A', 'C', 'C'] | 7 |

Comment: Thanks @tozCSS, is this guaranteed though to have the same indexing as the original dataframe? I have to combine both and can do a `pd.concat` operation if the indices are the same.

Comment: yes @irene please see how I assign it back to `df` as the new columns --changed the last line.

Comment: Upvoted but sorry I can't accept it as it was slower than my answer. Thank you though!